# Real Time data replication in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

We are facing a technical challenge for the below scenario. Any solution with any technology are welcome.

1. Our client has a legacy SQL Server replication system in place with one ERP source system with huge volume of data (daily transaction 3MN) and 5 target databases
2. All these target databases need real time data from source system and they have TRANSACTIONAL REPLICATION in place
3. Now the problem is this source ERP database involved in frequent changes like column additions in a table, rename of a column, new table additions. So to incorporate all this changes to subsequent target database, they need to REINITIALIZE the replication every time. At the same time to sync the data between source and target they need to down the source ERP system for a longer time, usually 7-8 hours, and sometimes up to 72 hours (3 days) if any issue arises during this REINITIALIZATION.

Is there any solution/technology using which we can smoothly propagate changes (both DDL and data changes) from source to target without any downtime?

The challenge here is the frequent DDL changes in the source ERP system.